# How can I change the docker unix service name to docker-ce?

Tags: linux, docker, sockets

I need to rename the docker.service to docker-ce.service. I know this is a bit unusual.

The reason being is I currently use kubespray to provision my kubernetes cluster and it installs containerd for me as the runtime. In addition to this, for some specific machines only, I also require docker to be installed on these machines. Kubespray is quite thorough when installing containerd as it goes ahead and uninstalls docker if it finds the service present. To overcome this, renaming the service of docker would work and allow kubespray to not uninstall it however this is proving quite troublesome.

Changing the service itself is simple, however the docker.socket no longer starts and errors with the following:

```
[root@vm01234 system]# systemctl status docker.socket
● docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
   Listen: /var/run/docker.sock (Stream)

Dec 09 16:47:04 vm01234 systemd[1]: docker.socket: Socket service docker.service not loaded, refusing.
Dec 09 16:47:04 vm01234 systemd[1]: Failed to listen on Docker Socket for the API.
```

Had a look through all the Docker docs and other threads but couldn't find anything. Hoping someone is able to help.

Running on RHEL 8.6.

For reference, here is are my service and socket files:

docker.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

docker-ce.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service containerd.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket containerd.service

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3

# Note that StartLimitInterval was renamed to StartLimitIntervalSec in systemd 230.
# Both the old, and new name are accepted by systemd 230 and up, so using the old name to make
# this option work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitInterval=60s

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity

# Comment TasksMax if your systemd version does not support it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this option.
TasksMax=infinity

# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process
OOMScoreAdjust=-500

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: what if you simply install docker after kubernetes?

Comment: There are day 2 operations we use with kubespray which will remove docker regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to solve the problem by adding a Service value to the [socket] block.

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker
Service=docker-ce.service

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```